# MongoDB aggregate order a nested object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a MongoDB aggerate, is it possible to to sort a nested object and keep it as an object instead of an $unwinded set of records.

EG. Take this collection:

```
"vehicles": [
  {
    "make": "ford",
    "VehicleImages": [
      {
        "image": "stuff5",
        "ShowOrder": 5
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff2",
        "ShowOrder": 2
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff3",
        "ShowOrder": 3
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff1",
        "ShowOrder": 1
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff4",
        "ShowOrder": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "make": "vahxhall",
    "VehicleImages": [
      {
        "image": "stuff2",
        "ShowOrder": 2
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff1",
        "ShowOrder": 1
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff4",
        "ShowOrder": 4
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff5",
        "ShowOrder": 5
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff3",
        "ShowOrder": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to transform it into the following, where the VehicleImages object is ordered by ShowOrder:

```
    "vehicles": [
  {
    "make": "ford",
    "VehicleImages": [
      {
        "image": "stuff1",
        "ShowOrder": 1
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff2",
        "ShowOrder": 2
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff3",
        "ShowOrder": 3
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff4",
        "ShowOrder": 4
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff5",
        "ShowOrder": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "make": "vahxhall",
    "VehicleImages": [
      {
        "image": "stuff1",
        "ShowOrder": 1
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff2",
        "ShowOrder": 2
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff3",
        "ShowOrder": 3
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff4",
        "ShowOrder": 4
      },
      {
        "image": "stuff5",
        "ShowOrder": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB version 5.2 introduced [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/#mongodb-expression-exp.-sortArray) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      VehicleImages: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$VehicleImages",
          sortBy: { ShowOrder: 1 }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2XgEapzks5t)